# Running program/macro to rename, add files to flash drive

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, copy, rename

I have a huge batch of flash drives that I need to move files onto. I'd also love to rename the drives (they're all called NO NAME by default). I'd love to plug two drives in, run a terminal script on the computer to accomplish all of that (most importantly the file moving). Then remove the drives, put the next two in, run it again, etc. until I'm done. All of the drives are identically named.

Is batch executing like this possible, and does anyone know how to go about doing it?

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: Mac OSX, I'll add that sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Put each one in and run this command to rename the drive and then move the files into it:

```
diskutil rename /Volumes/OLDNAME "NEWNAME" && cp -r ~/Desktop/sourceFolder/. /Volumes/NEWNAME
```